# Does Vercel ignore the next.config.js file on a preview domain?

Tags: next.js, cors, vercel

I am trying to setup a dev domain for my NextJS application on Vercel.

In my next.config.js I am allowing access to my API routes from any source. This works absolutely fine in my production environment.

I have a branch called `develop` that I have setup to run as a preview domain that I have configured to run on `dev.myapp.com`.

I have succesfully managed to have separate environment variables for production and my develop preview branch.

The problem I am finding is that for my open API routes, I always get a 401 unauthorized response.

How can I fix this?

I'm assuming Vercel is stopping me from opening up all sources to a preview URL?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the solution was to simply create my dev project as a new project in Vercel and then just assign the main production branch to my `develop` branch.